# Thoughts on Horizontal Scroll View with Reuse Views in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview

Hi I am still in shock that, there is no such support from android that has horizontal scroll view
my delima is as follows:
i need a horizontal scroll view, sure, fair enough, there is widget called

```
HorizontalScrollView
```

i can use this, and i like it, becuase it gives you this scroll feel.  problem is that i cannot use it, becuase it is not an adapterview, which means it doesn't RECYCLE the views.  this is not good becuase i have a lot of objects to display, i need those views that are being scrolled off, so i can re-use them.

now of course
an alternative would be

```
viewpager
```

this widget has an adapter, Great!! exactly what i want i can reuse view, problem the scrolling sucks...just try scrolling viewpager vs horizontal scroll view, horizontal scroll view is a lot smoother, and responds if you swipe it really hard, viewpager does not scroll good

and it also does not have this little scroll bar to indicate when you are in the scroll like horizontal scroll view does

i am trying to avoid 3rd party, unless it is really good and has no bug...if so , feel free to recommend it, but is it possible to create our own from custom? if so, how?

i want the smooth and scroll bar of horizontal scroll view and the reusability of views (adapter) in view pager

why android does not have such common widget that everyone will for sure use??

Comment: ViewPager seriously sucks. It's too slow.

Comment: i was going to ask if there is a way to speed up the scrolling speed of viewpager

Comment: The thing about ViewPager is it doesn't extend AdapterView therefore there is not "reusing" of view like in Listview. So each page is allocated a view object. Which is possibly why its so slow.

Comment: no, i think you are wrong with ViewPager, it does reuse view, it has pageadapter, and gives you the view that is being removed.  gallery is depreciated, and it is depreciated because it is not really 're-using' the views....

Comment: No it doesn't. Here [check](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java) it yourself.